# Best way to pass data from controller to template after form submit

Tags: php, magento, session

I have created a simple module called product selector. I use Magento collection to retrieve and filter specific products. The data to be used as filter will come from a form post action. As of now this is what I have done so far.

My Controller

```
public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $data['ta'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-action');
        $data['tr'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-required');
        $data['tm'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-metric');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

My phtml file

```
$attr_name = 'product_classification';
$attr_val = $form_data1; //example data only
$metric = $form_data2; //example data only
$metric_val_max = $form_data3; //example data only
$metric_val_min = 1000;

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldTofilter($attr_name, array(
                    'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute($attr_name)
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId($attr_val)
                    ))
                ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('lteq' => $metric_val_max))
                ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('gteq' => $metric_val_min))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->load();
```

My problem is that, I can't pass the data from controller to phtml template.

I tried to use Mage::getSingleton('core/session')

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSomeSessionVar($data);// In the Controller

$data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSomeSessionVar(); // In the View;
```

I successfully retrieve the data using core/session however, when I tried to put it on the collection it goes blank. $form_data1 = echo $data['ta'];

I also use Magento registry but no luck.

```
Mage::register('some_name', $data); //set on controller

$my_var = Mage::registry('some_name'); //Fetch on View
```

I successfully get the post form data to controller. I also successfully fetch specific data via Magento collection using fixed values.

QUESTIONS:

How do I pass data from controller to phtml template?
What are the best way to do it? Am I going to create a block class?

Thanks in advance.

These are my references
http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/send-data-from-the-controller-to-phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome!

One of the way to pass data from controller to any block or phtml is to use Magento register.

Controller: Set or register data using Mage::register('any string name', $data)

```
public function indexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();

        $data['ta'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-action');
        $data['tr'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-required');
        $data['tm'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torque-metric');
        Mage::register('t1', $data['ta']);
        Mage::register('t2', $data['tr']);
        Mage::register('t3', $data['tm']);

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Phtml: Get registered data using Mage::registry('your string name')

```
$_ta = Mage::registry('t1'); //torque action
$_tr_max = Mage::registry('t2'); //torque required
$_tm = Mage::registry('t3'); //torque metric
```

Note: This is actually simple to use just beware on your typos.

Thanks!